# Unknown Inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

$$ \left( \sqrt{3}\sqrt{y(x+y+z)}+\sqrt{xz}\right)\left( \sqrt{3}\sqrt{x(x+y+z)}+\sqrt{yz}\right)\left( \sqrt{3}\sqrt{z(x+y+z)}+\sqrt{xy}\right) \leq 8(y+x)(x+z)(y+z)$$

I can prove this inequality, but i need know if this inequaliy is known...

Comment: Although you might not like it, these types of problem can usually be solved by expanding the bracket.

Comment: Is that $(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)$ on the right?

Comment: Haven't finished it so put it in comment, Right-Left=$5(x^2y+xy^2+x^2z+xz^2+y^2z+yz^2)+6xyz-4\sqrt3(x+y+z)^{\frac{3}{2}} \sqrt{xyz}$

Comment: I did not see your inequality before. I proved your inequality and it's not so hard.

Comment: Michael Rozenberg  Show me your proof, please!I want to compare with my proof.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice and simple proof (for $x,y,z\ge 0$ of course):

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$\left( \sqrt{3}\sqrt{y(x+y+z)}+\sqrt{xz}\right)^2 \le (3+1)\big[(y(x+y+z) + xz\big] = 4(x+y)(y+z).$$
Similarly:
$$\left( \sqrt{3}\sqrt{x(x+y+z)}+\sqrt{yz}\right)^2 \le 4(x+z)(x+y)$$
$$\left( \sqrt{3}\sqrt{z(x+y+z)}+\sqrt{xy}\right)^2 \le 4(x+z)(y+z).$$
Taking the product of the above three inequalities we get the desired inequality.

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that
$$\prod\limits_{cyc}(a\sqrt{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}+bc)\leq8\prod\limits_{cyc}(a^2+b^2)$$
which is true even for all reals $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Indeed, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$, where $v^2$ can be negative, and $abc=w^3$.

Hence, it's obvious that the last inequality is equivalent yo $f(w^3)\leq0$, where $f$ is a convex function.
Hence, $f$ gets a maximal value for an extremal value of $w^3$.

We know that an equation $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=0$ or $x^3-3ux^2+3v^2x=w^3$ has three real roots $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Thus, a graph $y=w^3$ cross a graph $y=x^3-3ux^2+3v^2x$ in three points (maybe two of them coincide)

Let $u$ and $v^2$ be constants.

Hence, $w^3$ gets an extremal value for an equality case of two variables.

Id est, it remains to prove our inequality for $b=c=1$, which gives

$(x-1)^2(13x^2+34x+25)\geq0$, which is obvious. Done!

Comment: Smart ideia!Thank's!